# Type issue when assigning values to an object based on previous values of that same object

Tags: typescript

I have an object where I store values and also the previous values of those values. The keys of the previous values are postfixed with ":previous". So i.e. `foo` and `foo:previous`. Now when I try to assign the values to the previous values I get a type error `Type "foo" is not assignable to type "${K}:previous"`. I believe that typescript does not understand that they both have the same types. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to educate typescript that they are compatible. This is what I tried:

```
type PostfixKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as `${string & K}:previous`]: T[K];
}

type Foo2 = Foo & PostfixKeys<Foo>
type Foo = { "foo": string; "bar": boolean }

const test = <K extends keyof Foo>(key: K, foo: Foo2) => {
  foo[`${key}:previous`] = foo[key]; // <= Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '`${K}:previous`'.(2322)
}
```

What is the most comprehensible way to make this work?
Here is a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZ2AMwJYA8DSEQIDwAqAfFALxQDeAUFFANqZSoB2UA1jnMlAVAIYIoAAwAkFJACcWAcygAyKJgC+ALjASIAN1RwArgiEBdFTwaGA3FSVUqoSFABicOACYyj5-NiIUGbLjwnOCJbcGgg9wooACJkZ2iTSRlzGIAjPgkEqFTnABsIPlZrKgBjOGYkKGAISvI8Rgh0auYAE0EOEC4PYIAKDpNMABooOLgTIJcASjISalpRulEKDtV1LR19I3cFjosrKiA) with this code.

I tried using `T[keyof T]` instead of `T[K]` this would indeed fix the typing issue BUT typescript wound not understand the value associated to the key in regards to the `:previous` anymore i.e.:

```
type PostfixKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as `${string & K}:previous`]: T[keyof T];
}

type Foo2 = Foo & PostfixKeys<Foo>
type Foo = { "foo": string; "bar": boolean }

const test = <K extends keyof Foo>(key: K, foo: Foo2) => {
  foo[`${key}:previous`] = foo[key]; // <= works but
  const bat = foo["bar:previous"]; // <= is not type `string | boolean` instead of `boolean` as it was correctly when using T[K]
}
```

So this is also not an option unfortunately as I’d lose type safety.

Comment: FWIW, storing previous values in a separate structure will significantly simplify the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. Consider your assignment

```js
  foo[`${key}:previous`] = foo[key];
```

It might help to understand the error by considering that the `Foo2` type doesn't provide an explicit link between the values for `K` and `${K}:previous`.

As far as TS is concerned, `Foo2` contains a bunch of values and you're just trying to assign one to another – you may note that the error goes away if `bar` is amended to also have type `string`.

Not recommending this, but just consider for illustrative purposes if you had:

```js
type WithPrevious<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { value: T[K], previous: T[K] }
}
const testWithPrevious = <K extends keyof Foo>(key: K, foo: WithPrevious<Foo>) => {
  foo[key].previous = foo[key].value;
}
```

In this formulation, the types of `value` and `previous` are tied together, so the reassignment works.

So, going back to your assignment, you can just assert that anything assignable to a `Key` slot is assignable to a `${Key}:previous` slot:

```js
  foo[`${key}:previous` as K] = foo[key];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZ2AMwJYA8DSEQIDwAqAfFALxQDeAUFFANqZSoB2UA1jnMlAVAIYIoAAwAkFJACcWAcygAyKJgC+ALjASIAN1RwArgiEBdFTwaGA3FSVUqoSFABicOACYyj5-NiIUGbLjwnOCJbcGgg9wooACJkZ2iTSRlzGIAjPgkEqFTnABsIPlZrKgBjOGYkKGAISvI8Rgh0auYAE0EOEC4PYIAKDpNMABooOLgTIJcASjISalpRulEKDtV1LR19IX5BTEN3BY6LKxsAegAqKABBXOqJZj5gVE1oOIkAW11ch51WV6Zc3L6YASb7PKBgXQSMCIGpQFQAWmmZxOoXsAHVUMAABYwDTaPT4YiRGj0RgsdicbgEYyUKCaPiAiAmAhmYZrfH6ZlmKDWaxlCrAKo1YAY7G49YE9z1KCNZptCmdbhBIh9HADYajEyinF4jb4ZXTUizEkHHCGAB07L1+2cdEO5vpjMsSiAA)

Comment: Ah so close! Thank you @motto and thanks for the explanation! This makes sense, sad TypeScript does not understand the relation